# Select cities from table, which do not start with vowels and do not end with vowels

Tags: sql-server

Query the list of CITY names from STATION that do not start with vowels and do not end with vowels. Your result cannot contain duplicates.

`Station` table has the columns named as

```
id (int), 
city varchar(21),
state varchar2(2)
```

SOLUTION :

```
select distinct city from station 
Except
select distinct city from station where city like '[aeiou]%[aeiou]'
```

OR

```
select distinct city from station where city not like '[aeiou]%[aeiou]'
```

Both the queries are not working. Can someone please give input on this problem?

Comment: It will be good to give the structure of your table, some sample data and expected output for people to understand what is exactly required.

Answer (score 3):

Using [wildcard character not match](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/wildcard-character-s-not-to-match-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) will help in this case.

The following query will return the city names which are not started and not ended with vowels.

```
SELECT DISTINCT city FROM station 
WHERE (LOWER(city) LIKE '[^aeiou]%' AND LOWER(city) LIKE '%[^aeiou]');
```

**Demo** with some sample data:

```
DECLARE @Station TABLE (City VARCHAR (50));

INSERT INTO @Station (City) VALUES
('Abced'), ('EeepA'), ('CongE'), ('RaaaR'), ('KeeeK');

SELECT DISTINCT city FROM @station 
WHERE (LOWER(city) LIKE '[^aeiou]%' AND LOWER(city) LIKE '%[^aeiou]');
```

Output:

```
city
-----
KeeeK
RaaaR
```

[**Demo on db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=52bfc38cd4e67d3d33f41e5cdeb998d3)

Answer (score 0):

try with MySQL solution :

```
select distinct CITY from STATION where substr(CITY, 1, 1) not in ('a','e','i','o','u') and substr(CITY, -1, 1) not in ('a','e','i','o','u');
```

Here "distinct" will solve the problem of duplicate value and "substring" function extract substring from string . Substring also contain start & length .
For more details follow the link :- https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_substr.asp

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT city FROM station 
WHERE LEFT(city, 1) NOT IN ('a','e','i','o','u','A','E','I','O','U') 
AND RIGHT(city, 1) NOT IN ('a','e','i','o','u','A','E','I','O','U');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY 
FROM STATION 
WHERE CITY NOT REGEXP '^[aeiou]' AND CITY NOT REGEXP '[aeiou]$'
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me using MySQL:

```
select distinct CITY from STATION where CITY NOT RLIKE '^[aeiouAEIOU]' AND CITY NOT RLIKE '[AEIOUaeiou]$' GROUP BY CITY;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
   select distinct city from station 
where city not in(
select distinct city from station where city like '[aeiou]%')
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY
FROM STATION
WHERE CITY RLIKE '^[^aieouAEOIU]' OR CITY RLIKE  '[^aieouAEOIU]$'
```

Comment: SQL Server doesn't support `RLIKE`

Answer (score -1):

for oracle try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY FROM STATION WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(CITY,'^.*[^aeiouAEIOU]$') 
INTERSECT
SELECT DISTINCT CITY FROM STATION WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(CITY,'^[^aeiouAEIOU].*$');
```